# SkNode name nil on TouchesBegan with Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've got 4 `SKNode`'s in my Scene.

In `TouchesBegan` method, one of them has nil as name, even if I've assigned it on instantiation.

After touching another node, that node shows the correct name.

What could be the problem?

I'm a newbie with Sprite Kit Framework.

Here are initializations.

```
var rightPortBorder = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/5))
rightPortBorder.position = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-5, y: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2))
rightPortBorder.name = rightPortCategoryName
var rightPortBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rightPortBorder.size)
rightPortBody.friction = 0.0
rightPortBody.dynamic = false
rightPortBody.contactTestBitMask = portCategory
rightPortBorder.physicsBody = rightPortBody
rightPort = rightPortBorder
self.addChild(rightPortBorder)

var leftPortBorder = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/5))
leftPortBorder.position = CGPoint(x: 5, y: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2))
leftPortBorder.name = leftPortCategoryName
var leftPortBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: leftPortBorder.size)
leftPortBody.friction = 0.0
leftPortBody.dynamic = false
leftPortBody.contactTestBitMask = portCategory
leftPortBorder.physicsBody = leftPortBody
leftPort = leftPortBorder
self.addChild(leftPortBorder)

var topPortBorder = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/5, height: 10))
topPortBorder.position = CGPoint(x: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width/2), y:  UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height-5)
topPortBorder.name = topPortCategoryName
var topPortBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: topPortBorder.size)
topPortBody.friction = 0.0
topPortBody.dynamic = false
topPortBody.contactTestBitMask = portCategory
topPortBorder.physicsBody = topPortBody
topPort = topPortBorder
self.addChild(topPortBorder)

var bottomPortBorder = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/5, height: 10))
bottomPortBorder.position = CGPoint(x: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width/2), y: 5)
bottomPortBorder.name = bottomPortCategoryName
var bottomPortBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bottomPortBorder.size)
bottomPortBody.friction = 0.0
bottomPortBody.dynamic = false
bottomPortBody.contactTestBitMask = portCategory
bottomPortBorder.physicsBody = bottomPortBody
bottomPort = bottomPortBorder
self.addChild(bottomPortBorder)
```

And here's touches began method

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if let body = physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocation) {

         if body.node!.name == rightPortCategoryName {
            println("Began touch on right paddle")
            resetAllFlagsTouch()
            isFingerOnRightPort = true
        }
        else if body.node!.name == topPortCategoryName {
            println("Began touch on top paddle")
            resetAllFlagsTouch()
            isFingerOnTopPort = true
        }
        else if body.node!.name == bottomPortCategoryName {
            println("Began touch on bottom paddle")
            resetAllFlagsTouch()
            isFingerOnBottomPort = true
        }
        if body.node!.name == leftPortCategoryName {
            println("Began touch on left paddle")
            resetAllFlagsTouch()
            isFingerOnLeftPort = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code please! show how you assign the name, and your touches began and everything else thats relevant

Comment: I've added the code in the question!!

Comment: Have tested your code and none of nodes print `nil`. What's in `resetAllFlagsTouch()`?

Comment: I reset all flags "isFingerOn...Port"

Comment: And the problem isn't the node which is nil, but it's name.

Comment: Did you add a physics body (e.g., edge loop) to the scene?

Comment: Yes I did it. The strange thing is that it seems that bottom node is active ONLY after interaction with left border

Comment: So you adding an edge loop to `self`? Perhaps the scene is the node with its `name = nil`

Comment: But i don't understand why it does it ONLY with the bottom one, and why it works normally after I interact with the left one

Comment: You are right, the problem is that self intercepts touch in that case. Why does that node isn't called by touch? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem editing the touchesBegan method: instead of getting the node from the world, I used the method `locationInNode` to get my node.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

        if node.name == rightPortCategoryName {
            println("Began touch on right paddle")
            resetAllFlagsTouch()
            isFingerOnRightPort = true
        }
        else if node.name == topPortCategoryName {
            println("Began touch on top paddle")
            resetAllFlagsTouch()
            isFingerOnTopPort = true
        }
        else if node.name == bottomPortCategoryName {
            println("Began touch on bottom paddle")
            resetAllFlagsTouch()
            isFingerOnBottomPort = true
        }
        if node.name == leftPortCategoryName {
            println("Began touch on left paddle")
            resetAllFlagsTouch()
            isFingerOnLeftPort = true
        }

}
```